# Adding hyperlink markdown after "[] " renders the link incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

The hyperlink markdown seems to break when you have "[] " immediately before link text. I noticed having spaces between the bracket groups doesn't effect the  outcome. Maybe it should?

**Source:** `byte[] [link][1]`

**Example:** byte[] [link][1](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by properly putting your `byte[]` in code formatting. This will prevent the square brackets from being interpretted as a link. As to what is causing this problem, it's a lot of different parts of markdown colliding in a very unfortunate fashion as it tries to simply render in order. It happens in any scenario if you try to pre-empt a link with anything inside of a singular pair of square brackets, not just emptiness. The exact behavior you see is because the link text of your intended link is not a valid anchor.

---

First, specifying just the link footer anchor in brackets counts as a link. So if I have a link anchor of `[2]`, then just writing `[2]` will count as a link, like below.

> [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80503/adding-hyperlink-markdown-after-renders-the-link-incorrectly)

Second, adding a space between the link text and the link footer anchor is a legal action for markdown. So, `[Elegance] [2]` will render as just the same as if there was no space in the middle.

> [Elegance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80503/adding-hyperlink-markdown-after-renders-the-link-incorrectly)

What's breaking in the end is that there's the secret point that link anchors don't need to be numbers. Markdown is treating your string `byte[] [link][1]` by linking the first set of brackets as link text, and the text "link" as the *anchor*. Then, 1 ends up being treated as its own separate link.

It still renders visibly because there is no "link" anchor at the bottom, so it is treated like a broken link syntax. Now, if you had an anchor of "link" at the bottom, though, you'll get the following output for your string:

> byte[1]

You can't see anything, though, because there's nothing in the link text. But between the `[1]` and the `byte` is a link. Were I to add another anchor for 1, then it would render the 1 as a link as well as the emptiness. Since I don't, though, let's just see what `[Elegance] [1][2]` looks like.

> [Elegance] [1][2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80503/adding-hyperlink-markdown-after-renders-the-link-incorrectly)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Grace.

Comment: This is absolutely correct; it relates to the fact that [markdown allows a space between the two parts of the link definition](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link). Hence, e.g., adding a second space before `[link]` would have worked as well. /cc @Jeremy

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape one of the brackets.

byte[] [test](http://google.com)

```
byte\[] [test](http://google.com)
```

---